# Почему не работает рекурсия?

Tags: javascript

```js
function func(i) {
    console.log(i++);
    if (i < 10) {
        func();
    }
}
func(1);
```

Почему данный скрипт не увеличивает счетчик? Да еще и выводит NaN

Comment: вы забыли в `func` передать `i`

Answer (score 6):

Потому что аргумент передавать надо:

```js
function func(i) {
    console.log(i++);
    if (i < 10) {
        func(i);
    }
}
func(1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```